# Little endian to big endian in Groovy 2.0?

Tags: groovy, bit-manipulation

Whats the best way to convert a little endian number to a big endian number?

```
def i = 0x12345678;
def j = 0x78563412;
assert i == convert(j) // ?
```

I know I could mask the bytes and reorder them but what's a groovier way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Good ol' Java (SE5+):

```
assert i == Integer.reverseBytes(j)
```

but Groovier:

```
def convert = Integer.&reverseBytes
assert i == convert(j)
```